# Highcharts - distinguish mouse events on chart and data labels

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I'm trying to handle mouse events separately for data labels and chart slices in a pie chart. How could I distinguish whether the even handler was triggered from a data label or from a chart piece? The standard mouse event object doesn't seem to contain any kind of information that could be used to identify the origin of the event. Thanks!

Comment: You can distinguish it by investigating e.target, e.g. for labels it might be <tspan>, for slices <path>.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, `e.target` is not the element that triggered the event but the data object used to create the data point. I cannot find any information in the object that would help me identify the source of the event.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j4y6ehx3/ - e.target is a dom element, so the tagname can be used to identify the difference - even more obvious, a css class. Slices have  highcharts-point class.

Comment: Fair enough but I need mouseover and mouseout events. I tried adding those in your jsfiddle and it didn't work. I tried 'mouseover' and 'mouseout', also 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'. In any case, in my ng2 project using Typescript, the event.target is simply the data object. I have no idea how to change that.

Comment: If you need specific events you can always attach those on data labels objects - as you would normally do for regular dom elements. See the example https://jsfiddle.net/1dh3etd3/. For e.target - make a live example, e.g. on plunkr.